# How to call a keyword recurvisely in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a keyword which checks, if a button value is Completed, once it is found, I want that keyword to stop and return the status. However the the button value Completed is not fixed to any time interval. I want to call the keyword recursively to check for value of button at every 3 minutes.

```
*** Test Case ***
   Navigate to menu    Home  Status
   #Something here to call the keywrod `Check run status` for every 3 
   minutes until ${passd} is true or 30 minutes are passed. 


***Keywrod***
 Check run status
${btnValue}  Get Text   //button[@id="btn_status"]  
${passed} =   Run Keyword And Return Status   Should be Equal   ${btnValue}   
Completed   
[Return]   ${passed}
```

How to iterate this with time interval & How can we achieve this with robotframework?

Comment: Do you want to apply [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Formal_definitions) indeed or just repeat some actions?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Wait until keyword succeeds` The keyword will repeat executing until it succeeds you can specific the time to repeat the keyword like so

```
*** Test Case ***
Repeat Keyword Test
   Navigate to menu    Home  Status
   ${status} =  wait until keyword succeeds  30 minutes  3 minutes  Check run status


***Keywrod***
Check run status
  ${btnValue}  Get Text   //button[@id="btn_status"]  
  ${passed} =   Run Keyword And Return Status   Should be Equal   ${btnValue}  Completed      
  [Return]   ${passed}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to use Robot for status monitoring, but have you tried:

Loops: [How to write a loop while in Robot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36328595/how-to-write-a-loop-while-in-robot-framework).

Or invert the result and use to repeat if failed: [Wait Until Keyword Succeeds](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds).